# How to exclude column value when at least one where condition is true?

Tags: mysql

**category_sales**

| category_id | customer_id | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 203 | 1 | 2325 |
| 15 | 2 | 847 |

**brand_sales**

| brand_id | customer_id | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 108 | 1 | 2001 |
| 20 | 2 | 89 |

**product_sales**

| product_id | customer_id | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 112 | 1 | 1900 |
| 12 | 1 | 150 |
| 124 | 2 | 1091 |

```
SELECT id
FROM customers
WHERE
id IN (SELECT customer_id FROM category_sales WHERE category_id IN (...))
AND id NOT IN (SELECT customer_id FROM brand_sales WHERE brand_id IN (...))
AND id NOT IN (SELECT customer_id FROM product_sales WHERE product_id IN (...))
```

I am trying to get the list of customer IDs who bought or did not buy certain brands, products, and categories. The above query doesn't work as intended because the resulting list still has customers who bought certain brands or products that should have been filtered out by the query.

I first tried joining the three sales table with the customers table - did not work.
Then I tried using EXISTS and NOT EXISTS instead of the normal WHERE conditions - did not work.
Also tried using ORs instead of ANDs - did not work.
What am I missing?

The mysql version I am using is 5.7.12 and thus cannot use CTEs.

Comment: Show us an example where this fails, because it looks like it should work.  This is only going to show you IDs that satisfy ALL THREE criteria.

Comment: `I am trying to get the list of customer IDs who bought or did not buy certain brands, products, and categories. `  This is too vague. Please state EXACTLY what you want. e.g satisfy all three criteria which can be expressed as `customer_id NOT IN category_id AND customer_id NOT IN brand_id AND customer_id NOT IN product_id`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure with this statement

> I am trying to get the list of customer IDs who bought or did not buy certain brands, products, and categories.

But, I assume you want to get list of customer IDs listed BUT did not buy certain brands, product, and categories.

With above assumptions, your mistakes in your query only on the first condition . Your query should be like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM customers
WHERE
id NOT IN (SELECT customer_id FROM category_sales WHERE category_id IN (...))
AND id NOT IN (SELECT customer_id FROM brand_sales WHERE brand_id IN (...))
AND id NOT IN (SELECT customer_id FROM product_sales WHERE product_id IN (...))
```

To make it more readable, I will change it by using `LEFT JOIN`. Here is the sample code:

```
SELECT c.id
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN category_sales cat ON c.id = cat.customer_id AND cat.category_id IN (...)
LEFT JOIN brand_sales brand ON c.id = brand.customer_id AND brand.brand_id IN (...)
LEFT JOIN product_sales prod ON c.id = prod.customer_id AND prod.product_id IN (...)
WHERE cat.customer_id IS NULL AND brand.customer_id IS NULL AND prod.customer_id IS NULL;
```